# how to get hh:mm:ss in angularjs-datepicker

Tags: angularjs, datepicker, angular-daterangepicker

hi i am using angularjs datepicker functionality using `npm i angularjs-datepicker` working fine but i need to show time like(15-12-2017 05:14 PM) help how to format the datepicker here i mentioned reference link also i tired from controller it's came but when i click date picker date shown wrongly .there is any specify format is there help or how to solve that problem

https://www.npmjs.com/package/angularjs-datepicker

html

```
<div class="hackyhack" datepicker datepicker-class="test-custom-class" 
   date-format="dd-MM-y" >
 <input type="text" id="AddQuoteDate" name="QuoteDate" size="4"
 ng-model="QuoteDate" placeholder="Enter Quote Date"
 ng-change="QuoteDatechange(QuoteDate)"
 class="form-control angular-datepicker-input"
 required title="Enter Quote Date"/>
  </div>
```

Controller

```
  $scope.QuoteDatechange = function (Quotedate) {
 var date = new Date();
            var hours = date.getHours() > 12 ? date.getHours() - 12 : date.getHours();
            var am_pm = date.getHours() >= 12 ? "PM" : "AM";
            hours = hours < 10 ? "0" + hours : hours;
            var minutes = date.getMinutes() < 10 ? "0" + date.getMinutes() : date.getMinutes();
            var seconds = date.getSeconds() < 10 ? "0" + date.getSeconds() : date.getSeconds();
              time = hours + ":" + minutes + ":" + seconds + " " + am_pm;
            $scope.QuoteDate = Quotedate + " " + time;
            }
```

Comment: Show us the code that you have tried.

Comment: @ Keyur Shah update my question  kindly verfiy it

Answer (score 0):

According to the [DOCs](https://github.com/720kb/angular-datepicker#doc) you have to use the [AngularJs date format](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/date)

> **Option**: date-format=""
>
> **Type**: String
>
> **Default**: String(new Date())
>
> **Description**: Set the date format you want to use, see the list [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/date)

```
<datepicker date-format="dd-MM-yyyy hh:mm a" selector="form-control">
   <input type="text" ng-model="QuoteDate"/>
</datepicker>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's Working for me. Try this. Hope it will help you.

```
var currentdate = new Date();
var hours = currentdate.getHours();
var minutes = currentdate.getMinutes();
var ampm = hours >= 12 ? 'pm' : 'am';
hours = hours % 12;
hours = hours ? hours : 12; // the hour '0' should be '12'
minutes = minutes < 10 ? '0'+minutes : minutes;
var strTime = hours + ':' + minutes + ampm;
$scope.QuoteDate = pad(currentdate.getDate()) + "/"
                + pad(currentdate.getMonth()+1)  + "/"
                + currentdate.getFullYear() + " "
                + strTime;

function pad(s) { return (s < 10) ? '0' + s : s; }


<input type="text" id="AddQuoteDate" name="QuoteDate" size="4" ng-model="QuoteDate" placeholder="Enter Quote Date" class="form-control angular-datepicker-input" required title="Enter Quote Date"/>

   $('#AddQuoteDate').datetimepicker({
        minDate:new Date(),
        format: 'DD/MM/YYYY hh:mma'
    });
```

Comment: when select date time appears crct but not able change date once i select in date picker kindly check once

Comment: @jose please check I have edited answer, hope it will help you.

Comment: same problem once u use that datepicker above mentioned link and try then only u understand my pblm:) @Nikita